# Prove or disprove (p→q)→r and p→(q→r) are equivalent using Logical Equivalence Laws (no truth table)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I was able to show using a truth table that the two statements (p→q)→r and p→(q→r) are NOT equivalent, I need to now verify using equivalence laws, and I'm stuck. Any guidance would be very appreciated. Here's what I got so far;

(p → q) → r ≡ (¬p ∨ q) → r   --    By Logical equivalence involving conditional statements

(¬p ∨ q) → r ≡ ¬(¬p ∨ q) ∨ r --   By Logical equivalence involving conditional statements

¬(¬p ∨ q) ∨ r ≡ (¬¬p ∧ ¬q) ∨ r  -- By De Morgans Law

(¬¬p ∧ ¬q) ∨ r ≡ (p ∧ ¬q) ∨ r -- By Double Negation Law

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Apply the same "procedure" to p→(q→r) and compare the two results.

Comment: So, you now have a conjunctive normal form of the first one.  Do it for the other also.  See if they are the same.

Comment: For anyone wondering, the $(p, q, r)$ truth table rows for which the two expressions are different are $(0, 0, 0)$ and $(0, 1, 0)$.

Comment: Thank you for the comments :)
I know that the next step is to do the same for the other statement and compare, but is this first one done? I thought I had to get to a (T) or (F) value somehow? 

@ryang Unfortunately The instructor will not accept anything but using Logic equivalence as I have shown in my question

Comment: IF the two formulas are equivalent, you can work on $[(p→q)→r] \leftrightarrow [p→(q→r)]$ with equivalence laws until you reach T.

Comment: But you have already checked that the two formulas are not equivalent (using truth table). Thus, a possible approach (as per second comment above) is to produce [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) for both formula and verify that the two resulting formula are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I present one demonstration that the given propositions are not equivalent *using the equivalences of propositional calculus only*.

Since conjunction and disjunction have  full properties of commutativity, associativity and distributivity, I shall omit parentheses when there is no risk of ambiguity for the sake of better readability:

1. $\qquad (p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r$
2. $\qquad\equiv\neg(\neg p\vee q)\vee r$
3. $\qquad\equiv(p\wedge\neg q)\vee r$
4. $\qquad\equiv((p\wedge\neg q)\vee (p\wedge\neg p))\vee r$
5. $\qquad\equiv((p\wedge (\neg q\vee\neg p))\vee r$
6. $\qquad\equiv(p\vee r)\wedge\mathbf{(\neg q\vee\neg p\vee r)}$

---

1. $\qquad p\rightarrow (q\rightarrow r)$
2. $\qquad\equiv\neg p\vee\neg q\vee r$
3. $\qquad\equiv\neg p\vee((\neg q\vee r)\wedge (\neg r\vee r))$
4. $\qquad\equiv\neg p\vee((\neg q\wedge\neg r)\vee r)$
5. $\qquad\equiv(\neg p\vee(\neg q\wedge\neg r))\vee r$
6. $\qquad\equiv((\neg p\vee\neg q)\wedge(\neg p\vee\neg r))\vee r$
7. $\qquad\equiv(\neg p\vee\neg q\vee r)\wedge (\neg p\vee\neg r\vee r)$
8. $\qquad\equiv\mathbf{\neg p\vee\neg q\vee r}$

The first of the given propositions has the disjunctive form of the second one (bold-faced) as one of its conjuncts. The other conjunct makes the resultant truth-table differ from the second proposition unless it is a tautology, which is not.

Comment: Thank you so much, just curious, as I am new to learning this, what laws were used for steps 4 and five, in the first part? Are they named?

Comment: At step 4, one of the identity laws, $p\vee\bot\leftrightarrow p$ (the other one is $p\wedge\top\leftrightarrow p$) and the contradiction, $p\wedge\neg p\leftrightarrow\bot$ (its counterpart, the tautology, is $p\vee\neg p\leftrightarrow\bot$). At step 5, the distributivity, $p\wedge (q\vee r)\leftrightarrow (p\wedge q)\vee (p\wedge r)$ (the other one is $p\vee (q\wedge r)\leftrightarrow (p\vee q)\wedge (p\vee r)$.